# Multiple negative numbers with -1 (Dataframe)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `dftask` that contains a column `'SetupDuration2'`. I would like to multiply all negative numbers in this column with -1 to turn them into positive numbers.

SetupDuration2 contains only numbers. I couldn't find a good and simple solution to do this.

Hope you can help me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Juse use [`abs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.abs.html#pandas.DataFrame.abs):

```
df = df.abs()
```

no need to multiply by -1

Example:

```
In [11]:
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('abs'), data=np.random.randn(5,3))
df

Out[11]:
          a         b         s
0  0.644335 -0.274676  0.193521
1  0.135012 -1.280627  2.080928
2 -1.366230 -0.170578 -1.039821
3  1.133378  0.002642 -1.351743
4  0.891477  0.813485  1.722085

In [12]:
df = df.abs()
df

Out[12]:
          a         b         s
0  0.644335  0.274676  0.193521
1  0.135012  1.280627  2.080928
2  1.366230  0.170578  1.039821
3  1.133378  0.002642  1.351743
4  0.891477  0.813485  1.722085
```

Comment: So if I do dftask['SetupDuration2'] = dftask['SetupDuration2'].abs() it should work?

Comment: Yes that will take the absolute value for that column

Comment: Great!! Thank's for this simple solution :)!